# RXjava complicated async task

Tags: rx-java2

I am trying to use async rxjava flow to handle a complicated task.

I get list of metrics, and list of cities and get their values (list of date and value). Each metric is stored in a different db, so lots of HTTP calls are expected.

The result order means nothing so I want to:

run over all the metrics and asynchronously.
For every metric I want to run over all the cities asynchronously.
For every city and metric I want to create a HTTP call to fetch the data.

The end response should look like this:

```
"result": {
  "metric1": [
    {
      "cityId": 8,
      "values": [
        {
          "date": "2017-09-26T10:49:49",
          "value": 445
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-09-27T10:49:49",
          "value": 341
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cityId": 9,
      "values": [
        {
          "date": "2017-09-26T10:49:49",
          "value": 445
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-09-27T10:49:49",
          "value": 341
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metric2": [
    {
      "cityId": 8,
      "values": [
        {
          "date": "2017-09-26T10:49:49",
          "value": 445
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-09-27T10:49:49",
          "value": 341
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cityId": 9,
      "values": [
        {
          "date": "2017-09-26T10:49:49",
          "value": 445
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-09-27T10:49:49",
          "value": 341
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Got lost with all the observables. Which should be blocking, which should return a real value?

**EDIT: added code sample**
Here is what I have so far:

```
    1. for each metric (parallel I guess):


         Observable.from(request.getMetrics())
                            .subscribe(metric -> {
                                List metricDataList = getMetricData(metric, citiesList);
                                result.put(metric.getName(), metricDataList);
                            });

                return ImmutableMap.of("result",   result);


    2. Get metric data (according to cities):

        final List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                Observable.from(citiesList).subscribe(city ->
                        result.add(ImmutableMap.of(
                                "id", city.getId(),
                                "name", city.getName(),
                                "value", getMetricValues(metricType, city.getId())
                                     .toBlocking()
                                     .firstOrDefault(new ArrayList<>()))));

                return result;

3. According to metric I decide which service to invoke:
private Observable<List<AggregatedObject>> getMetricValues(AggregationMetricType metric, Integer cityId) {

        switch (metric) {
            case METRIC_1:        return fetchMetric1(city);
            case METRIC_2:        return fetchMetric2(city);
        }

        return Observable.empty();
    }


4. Invoke the service:

public Observable<List<AggregatedObject>> fetchMetric1(Integer city) {
        return Observable.just(httpClient.getData(city)
                .map(this::transformCountResult)
                .onErrorResumeNext(err -> Observable.from(new ArrayList<>()));
    }

5. Transform the received data:
protected List<AggregatedObject> transformCountResult(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        ...
    }
```

It is working, though I am not sure that I have implemented it correctly regarding blocking and concurrency.

Help please.

Regards,
Ido

Comment: You will have to show us the point where you got lost. For instance, are you able to do a single metric for a single city?

Comment: Thanks Bob.. Added code sample to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the step you call "2) get metric data", you could refactor as

```
    final List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.from(citiesList)
     .flatMap(city -> getMetricValues(metricType, city.getId())
                       .firstOrDefault(new ArrayList<>())
                       .map( metric -> ImmutableMap.of(
                                      "id", city.getId(),
                                      "name", city.getName(),
                                      "value", metric) ) )
     .toList()
     .toBlocking()
     .subscribe( resultList -> result = resultList );
```

Moving the `toBlocking()` outside of the processing means that individual requests will occur in a more parallel fashion.